# AWS EC2 instance showing IIS Page on Public IP even though localhost shows WAMP

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-ec2, wamp

I created a Windows 2016 Base EC2 Instance and installed IIS on it. But soon realized that I have to run WAMP to host PHP sites so I installed WAMP and stopped IIS service and everything was working fine.
Then I made a few changes to the site (It's a Wordpress site) and published it and since then the public IP is showing IIS page.

1. I have tried renamed iisstart.html to iisstart (to trick system into
   thinking the file doesn't exist) from IIS folder but the public IP
   is still showing IIS page.
2. I have tried restarting the instance machine. Localhost is showing my wordpress site but public/elastic IP shows IIS.
3. I have tried restarting WAMP, no luck.

I don't know how is it possible that IIS page is shown even when the file is renamed.

I have tried creating an Elastic IP as well but didn't worked.

Comment: Disable IIS or uninstall it. If its not at least disabled it will automatically start and be the first web server to grab port 80

Comment: The issue is going weird now. I have stopped my instance and the IP is still showing IIS homepage.
I think IP is redirecting to some wrong destination.

Comment: So I created a new EC2 instance, this time I didn't install IIS, I setup WAMP, wordpress and everything was working, IP was showing my site. 
Then I import my website posts from an xml, changed a few files here and there and AGAIN, IP started showing IIS page. IIS isn't even installed this time.
I tried putting default contents of WAMP in www folder but still IIS page is showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! So the issue is fixed! Now posting solution for anyone who will reach here (maybe my future self)
There was no issue with AWS EC2 or WAMP. The issue was in importing Wordpress.
When I imported Wordpress the Site Address and Wordpress Address changed to localhost. Due to which the IP was redirecting to localhost of destination machine.

Solution:
After you import your Wordpress, goto wp-admin -> Settings (in Side Bar)
And change the Site Address and Wordpress Address to the public/elastic IP of your instance.
Then clear Cache/Cookie on your destination machine and revisit the IP. It should work. (It did in my case)